# In Google Drive on iOS, how do you change sharing permissions to be anything other than "Private"?

Tags: ios, google-apps

In Google Drive on iOS, how do you change sharing permissions for a file or folder from "Private" to "Anyone with the link" or "Public on the web"?  I only see a way to add named users.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I cannot find a way but I did find a work around.  Open google drive via web browser and change view to desktop.  This option is located at the very bottom of the screen.  It's irritating but at least you can do it on your iPad.

Comment: The user is probably talking about the iOS application, rather than relying on a web-browser. But at least your answer does give an option. +1